# Al ingresar el valor de la temperatura debo determinar el tipo de clima

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Al  ingresar el valor de la temperatura debo determinar el tipo de clima. debe realizarse con Windows forms.

> Temperatura <10 = Frio
>
> Temperatura >10 y <=20 = Nublado
>
> temperatura >=21 y <=30 = Calor
>
> temperatura >30 =Tropical

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
 private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtTipoClima.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar la Temperatura (Solo Números)", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                if (temperatura <10)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Frio", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (temperatura >10 && temperatura <= 20)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nublado", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (temperatura >= 21 && temperatura <= 30)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Calor", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (temperatura > 30)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Tropical", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

No logro definir todos los tipos de temperatura, solo funciona este fragmento del código:

```
if (temperatura <10)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Frio", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate que cuando entras a este método temperatura tiene el valor que has introducido en el cuadro de texto.

Lo que parece es que no le asignas el valor y siempre vale 0, con lo cual siempre te ingresa en el primer if. Nada más entrar al método haz:

```
temperatura = Int32.Parse(txtTipoClima.Text); //Asumo que es un entero, sino pásalo a double
```

Ahora, teniendo el valor de la temperatura si que puedes hacer las comparaciones (mejor utilizando else if):

```
temperatura = Int32.Parse(txtTipoClima.Text);

if (txtTipoClima.Text == string.Empty){
    MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar la Temperatura (Solo Números)", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}else if (temperatura <=10){
          MessageBox.Show("Frio", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}else if (temperatura >10 && temperatura <= 20){
          MessageBox.Showw("Nublado", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}else if (temperatura >= 21 && temperatura <= 30){
          MessageBox.Show("Calor", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}else if (temperatura > 30){        
      MessageBox.Show("Tropical", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes saber que existe una sentencia para comparar resultados complementaria para el if siendo esta else if intenta con este codigo , (No tengo IDE de C#) 
`

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (txtTipoClima.Text == string.Empty){
        MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar la Temperatura (Solo Números)", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }else if (temperatura <10){
              MessageBox.Show("Frio", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }else if (temperatura >10 && temperatura <= 20){
              MessageBox.Showw("Nublado", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }else if (temperatura >= 21 && temperatura <= 30){
              MessageBox.Show("Calor", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }else if (temperatura > 30){        
          MessageBox.Show("Tropical", "Mensaje del Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: No sabia como hacer lo de else if , pero aun así no me funciona, solo entra  en la primer condición.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código funciona bien quizás el error es cuando guardas en la variable temperatura, debería ser de esta forma

```
int temperatura = int.Parse(txtTipoClima.Text);
```

el unico error es que si ingresas 10 no entra en ninguna condición if podrías cambiar la primera de tal manera que diga menor o igual a 10

```
if (temperatura <= 10){
```